# Trouble entering data into MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been checking my syntax all night yet I can't seem to see what is wrong. I'm relatively new to all this and would appreciate nay help that may be provided. The error I'm getting is

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ID','Name','Option','Sides') VALUES(NULL,'Denise','Chicken','Mashed Potat' at line 1"

My code is below:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$name = $_POST['inputName'];
$opt = $_POST['inputOption'];
$side = $_POST['inputSides'];

if(!$_POST['Submit']) {
    echo "Please fill out the form.";
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO people ('ID','Name','Option','Sides')
                VALUES(NULL,'$name','$opt','$side')") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "User has been added.";
    header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong [**identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for your columns:

```
('ID','Name','Option','Sides')
```

Either remove the quotes or wrap them in backticks.

```
(`ID`,`Name`,`Option`,`Sides`)
```

Plus, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Another thing; should you want to be entering apostrophes, use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) including [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). The occasion may very well present itself; *an insight*.

- Otherwise, SQL will throw another error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even realize. Everything works flawlessly now.